# Convert MSSQL to mysql table

Tags: mysql, sql-server

Can I know the easiest way to convert the Microsoft sql query to MYSQL.

sample query of Microsoft sql query:

```
   CREATE TABLE [dbo].[T_NEWBIZ](
[newbID] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
[planID] [int] NULL,
[applID] [int] NULL,
[taxqID] [int] NULL,
[doptID] [int] NULL,
[stcoID] [int] NULL,
[crsnID] [int] NULL,
[newbEPBR] [bit] NULL,
[newbPolicyNo] [varchar](50) NULL,
[newbEffectiveDate] [varchar](20) NULL,
[newbIssueDate] [varchar](20) NULL,
[newbDistributorOrderNumber] [varchar](30) NULL,
[newbJointAnnuitantNA] [bit] NULL,
[newbOwnerIsAnnuitant] [bit] NULL,
[newbDeliveryEMail] [varchar](100) NULL,
[newbDeliveryConsent] [bit] NULL,
[newbAnnuityOptionSpecialRequest] [varchar](500) NULL,
[newbCSRID] [varchar](20) NULL,
[newbBrokerID] [varchar](10) NULL,
[newbUGMA] [bit] NULL,
[newbUTMA] [bit] NULL,
[newbRecapAvailable] [bit] NULL,
[newbOriginatorCode] [varchar](8) NULL,
[newbFileNetStatus] [char](1) NULL,
[newbJointOwnerNA] [bit] NULL,
[newbNameChange] [bit] NULL,
[newbDateCompleted] [datetime] NULL,
[newbSuitabilityStatus] [varchar](25) NULL,
[newbClientNumber] [varchar](15) NULL,
[newbCheckPayable] [bit] NULL,
[newbMSANumber] [varchar](11) NULL,
[newbPrincipalReviewer] [varchar](10) NULL,
[newbCreationDate] [datetime] NULL,
[newbAnyExistingPolicies] [varchar](1) NULL,
[newbCreatedBy] [varchar](50) NULL,
[newbReplaceExistingPolicy] [varchar](1) NULL,
[newbFormsVerified] [bit] NULL,
[newbTransfer1035] [varchar](1) NULL,
[newbFormsComment] [varchar](500) NULL,
[newbADRequired] [bit] NULL,
[newbAssignedCSRID] [varchar](10) NULL,
[newbBackupWithholding] [varchar](1) NULL,
[newbSuitabilityApprovedDate] [datetime] NULL,
[newbExchangeInternal] [bit] NULL,
[newbAnnuityDate] [varchar](20) NULL,
[newbAnnuityDateOverride] [bit] NULL,
[newbAnnuityOption] [varchar](1) NULL,
[newbSpecialRequest] [varchar](500) NULL,
[newbSpecialRequestNA] [bit] NULL,
[newbFraudAccepted] [bit] NULL,
[newbHireDate] [varchar](20) NULL,
[newbAppless] [bit] NULL,
[newbMailToClient] [bit] NULL,
[newbPGR] [bit] NULL,
[newbDataLock] [varchar](8) NULL,
[amlsCode] [varchar](1) NULL,
[newbFEPlanCodeIndicator] [bit] NULL,
[newbFEPlanCodeDate] [varchar](10) NULL,
[newbBestPlusClientID] [varchar](10) NULL,
[newbDetachedOfficeIndicator] [char](1) NULL,
[newbDetachedOfficeCode] [varchar](5) NULL,
[newbPreviousWFM] [bit] NULL,
[newbARDForm1] [bit] NULL,
[newbARDForm2] [bit] NULL,
[newbARDForm3] [bit] NULL,
[newbARDForm4] [bit] NULL,
[newbARDForm5] [bit] NULL,
[newbPSO] [bit] NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PKC_NewBiz_cnewbID] PRIMARY KEY NONCLUSTERED 
 (
  [newbID] ASC
 )WITH (PAD_INDEX  = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE  = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY =   OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS  = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS  = ON, FILLFACTOR = 95) ON   [PRIMARY]
 ) ON [PRIMARY]
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use mysql workbench to do so, I converted mssql database to MySQL database.

Here is the [link](http://mysqlworkbench.org/2012/07/migrating-from-ms-sql-server-to-mysql-using-workbench-migration-wizard/comment-page-1/) to tutorial, it has all the details along with screenshots.